# CUDNN_STATUS_MAPPING_ERROR when training with pose2body

Tags: deep-learning, pytorch

I'm trying to train https://github.com/NVIDIA/vid2vid. I'm...

- ...executing with pretty much the vanilla parametrization shown in the readme, I had to change the number of GPUs though and increased the number of threads for reading the dataset. Command:

  `python train.py \
  --name pose2body_256p  \
  --dataroot datasets/pose  \
  --dataset_mode pose  \
  --input_nc 6  \
  --num_D 2  \ 
  --resize_or_crop ScaleHeight_and_scaledCrop  \
  --loadSize 384  \
  --fineSize 256  \
  --gpu_ids 0,1  \
  --batchSize 1  \
  --max_frames_per_gpu 3  \
  --no_first_img  \
  --n_frames_total 12  \
  --max_t_step 4  \
  --nThreads 6`
- ...training on the supplied example datasets.
- ...running a docker container built with the scripts in `vid2vid/docker`, e. g. with CUDA 9.0 and CUDNN 7.
- ...using two NVIDIA V100 GPUs.

Whenever I start training the script crashes after a couple of minutes with the message **`RuntimeError: CUDNN_STATUS_MAPPING_ERROR`**. Full error message:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "train.py", line 329, in <module>
    train()
  File "train.py", line 104, in train
    fake_B, fake_B_raw, flow, weight, real_A, real_Bp, fake_B_last = modelG(input_A, input_B, inst_A, fake_B_last)            
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/torch/nn/modules/module.py", line 491, in __call__
    result = self.forward(*input, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/torch/nn/parallel/data_parallel.py", line 114, in forward
    outputs = self.parallel_apply(replicas, inputs, kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/torch/nn/parallel/data_parallel.py", line 124, in parallel_apply
    return parallel_apply(replicas, inputs, kwargs, self.device_ids[:len(replicas)])
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/torch/nn/parallel/parallel_apply.py", line 65, in parallel_apply
    raise output
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/torch/nn/parallel/parallel_apply.py", line 41, in _worker
    output = module(*input, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/torch/nn/modules/module.py", line 491, in __call__
    result = self.forward(*input, **kwargs)
  File "/vid2vid/models/vid2vid_model_G.py", line 130, in forward
    fake_B, fake_B_raw, flow, weight = self.generate_frame_train(netG, real_A_all, fake_B_prev, start_gpu, is_first_frame)        
  File "/vid2vid/models/vid2vid_model_G.py", line 175, in generate_frame_train
    fake_B_feat, flow_feat, fake_B_fg_feat, use_raw_only)
  File "/vid2vid/models/networks.py", line 171, in forward
    downsample = self.model_down_seg(input) + self.model_down_img(img_prev)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/torch/nn/modules/module.py", line 491, in __call__
    result = self.forward(*input, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/torch/nn/modules/container.py", line 91, in forward
    input = module(input)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/torch/nn/modules/module.py", line 491, in __call__
    result = self.forward(*input, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/torch/nn/modules/conv.py", line 301, in forward
    self.padding, self.dilation, self.groups)
RuntimeError: CUDNN_STATUS_MAPPING_ERROR
```

From reading the issues in the vid2vid using two V100 should work with this setup. The error also occurs if CUDA 8/CUDNN 6 are used. I checked the flags but haven't found any indication of further necessary changes to the arguments supplied to `train.py`.

Any ideas on how to solve (or work around) this?

Answer (score 2):

In case anybody deals the same issue: Training on P100 cards worked. Seems like the V100 architecture clashes with version of pytorch used in the supplied Dockerfile at some point. Not quite a solution, but a workaround.